# How to align TextBlock = Stretch in a listbox template?

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, xaml, styles

I'm trying to create a listbox template (for the items). This is what I've got.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
                <TextBlock Text="TEKS" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Background="#FF502F8F"  Foreground="White" Width="{Binding Path=Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Level}" FontSize="24" Background="#FF058C44" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="{Binding Path=Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}}" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" />
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Owner}" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SampleDataSource}}">
    <ListBox ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" Margin="44,39,82,103" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

And this is image how it looks.

[image]

Can you see the textblock extends more the width? I want to show the string wrap inside the listbox. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to set the width of the text block - otherwise it will grow to accommodate the content.

Comment: Did you try width=auto for the textblock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Disable horizontal scrolling:

   ```
   <ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ...>
   ```
2. Enable text wrapping (already the case):

   ```
   <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" ...>
   ```

Comment: Guau, it works H.B. One more question, do you know how to align all the textblockes inside the stack panel (I mean strentch).

Comment: You currently set `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` on the lower `TextBlock` that should be set to `Stretch`.